# unexpected apache redirection

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

I'm trying to make all http versions of my pages redirect to the https version, however I am having some problems with redirection.

I want `http://stackexchange.com/path/` to go `https://stackexchange.com/path/` but instead it is redirecting to https://stackexchange.compath

Here is my configuration for the virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName stackexchange.com
ServerAlias www.stackexchange.com   
Redirect / https://stackexchange.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName stackexchange.com
ServerAlias www.stackexchange.com
SSLEngine on
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generally do the HTTP -> HTTPS redirection using just mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It's often best to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` vs. `$1`.

If however you do not want to use mod_rewrite, or do not have that Apache module at your disposal you can use redirect like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs 
   Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

#### References

- [Apache Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using mod_rewrite](http://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html)
- [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)

Comment: ... and then `SSLRequireSSL` the DocumentRoot `<Directory>` to make sure that trying non-encrypted access is an immediate "403 unauthorized", just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need `mod_rewrite` for this purpose:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName stackexchange.com
ServerAlias www.stackexchange.com
SSLEngine on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
...
```

Enable `mod_rewrite` then restart apache to apply changes.